# Default parameter for partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization, default-parameters

What syntax I want to achieve on user side:

```
double a(1.), b(2.), deps(.1);
bool res1 = compare<double>()(a, b);        // works with default eps
bool res2 = compare<double, &deps>()(a, b);  // works with explicitly provided eps
float c(1.), d(1.). feps(.1);
bool res3 = compare<float>()(c, d);  // don't have default eps - must not compile
bool res4 = compare<float, &feps>()(c, d);   // works only with provided eps
```

What implementation for this I have now (not working because default parameters for partial specialization are not allowed):

```
extern double eps_double; // somewhere defined and initialized

template<typename T, const T* eps>
struct compare { // actually inherits std::binary_function
  bool operator()(const T& t1, const T& t2) {
    return t1 < t2 - *eps;
  }
};
template<const double* eps = &eps_double>
struct compare<double, eps> { // the same as in default implementation
};
```

I've tried with enable_if and wrapper classes that have static members, but static members can't be assigned to extern variables;

**UPDATE:**
The actual problem is name equality for general struct and specialized struct. I don't know how to make it work without renaming:

```
// treats all explicitly passed eps and don't need default parameter
template<typename T, const T* eps>
struct compare_eps { // need another name! 
  bool operator()(const T& t1, const T& t2) {
    return t1 < t2 - *eps;
  }
};
// don't need default parameter either
// because we always know what eps to use for a concrete type
template<typename T>
struct compare { 
  // define nothing -> will not compile on types we don't have specialization for
}; 
template<>
struct compare<double> { 
  // use here eps_double hardcoded
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you think that this make sense

```
compare<double, deps>
```

You cannot make this work: Template arguments cannot be values of type `double` (they can be an lvalue of type `double`, but your template requires the address of a `double`, so that's off).

You can use function templates to make your syntax work

```
extern double eps_double;

template<typename T>
types::compare<T, &eps_double> compare(
  typename enable_if<is_same<T, double>>::type * = 0
) {
  return types::compare<T, &eps_double>(); 
}

template<typename T, const T *eps>
types::compare<T, eps> compare() {
  return types::compare<T, eps>(); 
}
```

Alternatively, you can use class templates if you are up for some ugly hacks

```
template<typename T, const T* eps = &eps_double>
struct compare { 
  bool operator()(const T& t1, const T& t2) {
    return t1 < t2 - *eps;
  }
};
```

The default argument will not be used if you provide both arguments. If you provide only `<double>`, the default argument will be used and will work. If you only provide `<float>`, the default argument will be used too, but will not work.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, the correct version is `compare<double, &deps>()(a, b);` of coarse. Please, see my update in the question.

Comment: @Johannes, what do you mean in your last paragraph "If you only provide <float>, the default argument will be used too, but will not work"?

Comment: @litb The reason why I can't use your last approach is that I have specialization not only for double, but for another types too.

Comment: @litb your first approach is very nice, thank you, I like it.

Comment: @Nim if he only passes the argument for `T`, and `T` is not `double` or `const double` or some other combination of qualifiers with `double`, for example `float`, then the use of `&eps_double` as default argument will be ill-formed and rejected.

Comment: @litb the only problem in your solution is one can't use `compare` via `typedef`, so providing it in traits is somewhat unclear

Comment: @Johannes, I see, I didn't realise that it will be so strict, so it will be compile time - cool.

Comment: @Riga you could instead use the address of a class static variable and then use as default argument `&check<T>::eps`, where `check<T>::eps` is only defined for all the types you have specializations for. Then, it would also work for multiple specializations.

Comment: @litb Anyway, I've accepted your answer because it elegantly solves initial formal problem.

Comment: @litb if `check<T>::eps` is static, I can't set it equal to external value, I've tried it

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the structure which owns the comparison operator such that you can specialize the outer template, see: http://ideone.com/xqtjz

the code is:

```
extern double eps_double; // somewhere defined and initialized
extern double deps;  // NOTE: you have to make these extern a well, else cannot work
extern float feps;

template<typename T>
struct compare {
  // this internal structure now has the operator()
  template <const T* eps>
  struct it
  {
    bool operator()(const T& t1, const T& t2) const {
      return t1 < t2 - *eps;
    }
  };
};

// specialize compare for double
template<>
struct compare<double>
{
  // here you can provide the default
  template<const double* eps=&eps_double>
  struct it
  {
    bool operator()(const double& t1, const double& t2)
    {
      return t1 < t2 - *eps;
    }
  };
};

int main(void)
{
  double a(1.), b(2.);
  bool res1 = compare<double>::it<>()(a, b);        // works with default eps
  bool res2 = compare<double>::it<&deps>()(a, b);   // works with explicitly provided eps
  float c(1.), d(1.);
  bool res3 = compare<float>::it<>()(c, d);  // don't have default eps - will not compile
  bool res4 = compare<float>::it<&feps>()(c, d);   // works only with provided eps
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that I can't pass non-extern argument as a template parameter. This makes all my use model not practical. Maybe I should pass eps as a parameter to `compare` functor instead. Your approach makes one smart thing - it separates problems - `T` specialization and `eps` specialization, good common practice, thank you!

Comment: the problem in your approach is that one cannot use compare as a typedef and provide class with all necessery information for comparison encapsulated, instead user must write eps at every invoke.

Comment: @Riga, only when you don't use the default double eps. You can for example `typedef compare<double> comp_double;`, then `comp_double::it<>(a,b);` works with the default eps. You only ever need to provide it when you use a given eps, but then you can typedef that too: `typedef typename compare<float>::it<&feps> comp_float;`, then `comp_float()(c, d);` - is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, I didn't know that I can create inner classes outside of a class like using typedefs.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with traits-like approach:

```
template<class T>
struct DefaultEps;

template<>
struct DefaultEps<double>
{
  static const double eps = 4.0;
};

// may or may not be needed in .cpp
// const double DefaultEps<double>::eps;

template<>
struct DefaultEps<float>
{
  static const float eps = 4.0;
};

// may or may not be needed in .cpp
// const float DefaultEps<float>::eps;

template<class T, class E = DefaultEps<T> >
struct Compare
{
  bool operator()(T const &t1, T const &t2)
  {
    return(t1 < t2 - E::eps);
  }
};
```

and then when specific epsilon is needed:

```
struct SpecificEps
{
  static const float eps = 4.0;
};

// may or may not be needed in .cpp
// const float SpecificEps::eps;
```

and use it:

```
Compare<float, SpecificEps>()(...);
```

Comment: hi! At first, your code will not compile because standard forbids inline initialization of non-integer variables. At second, I can't assign my externally defined constant to a static member variable in header. If I have header-only library, I will have to put initialization of every new eps in every context to the special .cpp file (I admit that it came not from your code). At third, traits class must be defined for every new eps. Your proposal requires more from user then other ones mentioned here. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Interesting, g++ 4.4.4 compiled it... I confirm however I haven't checked it against standard.